# How is the E argument calculated for a given G1 command?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, extrusion

I'm working on building a tool to generate G-code (a simpler slicer), and I'm trying to calculate how much filament should be extruded per movement.

Is there a standard calculation for this? Something like:

```
layer height * flow % * extruder diameter * distance
```

How does Ultimaker Cura calculate this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, all movements are (small) straight lines, the volume of a straight line is easily calculated as you already guessed.

To calculate the volume to be extruded you multiply the following parameters:

- the layer height *(h)*
- flow modifier (e.g. as percentage) *(SF)*
- extruder nozzle diameter *(d<sub>n</sub>)* (or extruder line width if different from nozzle diameter)
- distance of the straight line *(l)*

With this volume you can calculate how much filament you need to extrude. To get the length (thus the length defined by the `E` parameter), divide the obtained volume by surface area of your used filament by:

- π * (filament radius)<sup>2</sup> or alternatively π /4 * (filament diameter)<sup>2</sup> = (π /4 * d<sub>f</sub><sup>2</sup>)

To sum up, the value of E is given by:

$$ E_{value} = \frac{h \times {SF} \times d_{n} \times l}{\frac{\pi}{4}d_{f}^2} = \frac{4 \times h \times {SF} \times d_{n} \times l}{\pi \times d_{f}^2} $$

Comment: Ultimately the volumetric extruder advance is modelled here just as the volume of a cube. Where there is a little bit of interesting room for variation is how you model the start/stop of the line, where it's not a flat edge but rounded.

Comment: I've taken the begin and end in consideration once, it doesn't make a real difference. (Unless you have very short lines to fill...)