# How is the Ex.xxx calculated?

Tags: extrusion

How is the `Ex.xxx` calculated, formula

```
G1 X129.000 Y126.322 E7.90758
G1 X128.476 Y125.548 E7.92045
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [How is the E argument calculated for a given G1 command?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6289/how-is-the-e-argument-calculated-for-a-given-g1-command) and has been [answered](/a/6290).